# getting id of parent element in rails rjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rjs, erb

I'm working with a that allows the user to add new contents to a shipment box.  For example:

The user is setting up a shipment, each shipment can include multiple boxes, and each box can contain multiple contents.

So I have `link_to_remote` connected like:

In my shipment box partial:

```
<div class="shipping_box" id="shipping_box">
    #some code
    <%= link_to_remote "Add box conents", :url => {:action=> 'add_box_contents'} %>
</div>
```

In `add_box_contents.rjs`:

```
page.insert_html :bottom, "shipping_box", :partial => 'box_content', :object => BoxContent.new
```

and in `_box_content.erb`

```
<div class="box_contents" id="box_contents">
   box contents partial rendered
</div>
```

For my first shipping box everything works fine, but when a second shipping box is added dynamically, the `_box_content.erb` partial is always rendered in the `<div>` for the first box.  Of course this is becuase the id was specified as `shipping_box`, and all boxes share this id.  My question then, is how do I have the new box contents partial rendered in the div for the correct containing box, not just aways the first box?

This screen shot shows the first box with 2 dynamically added contents lines (the drop downs).  I would like the "add order line item" line for the second box to add a drop down list to the contents of my second box.  [alt text http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/6274/screenshot20100622at114.png](http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/6274/screenshot20100622at114.png)

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you using the jRails plugin? (hoping so; then we can use jQuery)

Comment: Not currently, but if that's the cleanest way, that I can be.  What's your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Your rjs should probably be using `replace_html()` instead of `insert_html()`

```
page.replace_html "shipping_box", :partial => 'box_content', :object => BoxContent.new
```

Comment: I'm trying to add multiple instances of new box contents.  I added a screen shot for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You actually want to render a partial "select_order_line", so that only the corresponding part is added to the shipping box. So just factor it out, then you can write:

```
page.insert_html :bottom, "box_content", :partial => 'select_order_line'
```